# Python fails to import packages within same folder structure

Tags: python, import

I'm creating a personal application with `flask_restful`, and I was doing everything with a single `models.py` and `app.py`, but the application is going to grow so I decided to make some folder restructuring.

I currently have the following structure:

```
/project_folder
    application_name
        __init__.py
        controllers.py
        models.py
    config.py
    manage.py
    run.py
    tests
        __init__.py
        test_controller.py
```

Everything works so far, but I want the structure to be the following:

```
/project_folder
    application_name
        __init__.py
        controllers
            __init__.py
            brewery_controller.py
            ...others
        models
            __init__.py
            base_model.py 
            brewery.py
            ...others
    config.py
    manage.py
    run.py
    tests
        __init__.py
        test_controller.py
```

But I can't seem to make it work. Here is the application `__init__.py`

```
#/project_folder/application_name/__init__.py
import os

from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_restful import Api

from controllers import BreweryList, BreweryResource
from models import db 

def initApp(config):

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

    db.init_app(app)
    api = Api(app)

    api.add_resource(BreweryList, '/breweries')
    api.add_resource(BreweryResource, '/breweries/<brewery_id>')

    return app
```

I tried with

```
from brewery_controller import BreweryList, BreweryResource
from base_model import db
```

with no luck. I keep getting `ImportError: cannot import BreweryList` and the same goes for `db` if I uncomment the Brewery classes import line.

The `controllers/__init__.py` and `models/__init__.py` are both empty.

Here is also the `run.py`

```
import os

from beerinv import initApp

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = initApp(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])
    app.run()
```

Comment: did you try `from controllers.brewery_controllers import ...`?

Comment: You're missing some dots: `from .models import db` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could solve the issue by following @davidism comment by putting full import path:

```
from application_name.controllers.brewery_controller import BreweryList, BreweryResource
from application_name.models.base_model import db
```